# Tomcat JAASRealm : Getting "Class not added" after starting server

Tags: java, authentication, jaas, tomcat5.5

I am using http://blog.frankel.ch/custom-loginmodule-in-tomcat tutorial for tomcat JAASRealm.I have added below in server.xml

Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JAASRealm" appName="CustomLogin"
  userClassNames="ch.frankel.blog.loginmodule.PlainUserPrincipal"
  roleClassNames="ch.frankel.blog.loginmodule.PlainRolePrincipal"
  />

while starting server i am getting

> INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/5.5.27
>   Jun 8, 2012 1:18:24 PM org.apache.catalina.realm.JAASRealm parseClassNames
>   **SEVERE: Class ch.frankel.blog.loginmodule.PlainUserPrincipal not found! Class no
>   t added.**
>   Jun 8, 2012 1:18:24 PM org.apache.catalina.realm.JAASRealm parseClassNames
>   **SEVERE: Class ch.frankel.blog.loginmodule.PlainRolePrincipal not found! Class no
>   t added**.
>   Jun 8, 2012 1:18:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost start
>   INFO: XML validation disabled
>   Jun 8, 2012 1:18:24 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
>   INFO: Deploying web application archive CustomLogin.war

I am using tomcat 5.5.27. When i call my servlet authentication is working fine but authorization is having some issue and might be due to **"Class not added."**

Please help....

Comment: may has something todo with this bug https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=44084

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It got resolved...I added a jar containing above classes in /server/lib folder and its working fine.